# C# MEF: Exporting multiple objects of one type, and Importing specific ones

Tags: c#, wpf, import, export, mef

I have an application which exports several objects of the same Class, and plugins which import only specific ones. for example

```
public class Part
{
  string name;
  public Part(string nm)
  {
    name = nm;
  }
}

public class Car //Exports ALL Parts of the Car
{
  [Export(typeof(Part))]
  public Part steeringWheel = new Part("SteeringWheel");

  [Export(typeof(Part))]
  public Part engine = new Part("Engine");

  [Export(typeof(Part))]
  public Part brakes = new Part("Brakes");
}

public class SystemMonitorPlugin //Imports only SOME Parts from the Car
{
  [Import(typeof(Part))]
 public Part engine;

  [Import(typeof(Part))]
  public Part brakes;
}
```

Could someone explain how I can achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a contract(interface) and a metadata contract (interface):

```
public interface ICarPart{
    int SomeMethodFromInterface();
}

public interface ICarPartMetadata{
    string /*attention to this!!!*/ NameCarPart { get; } /* Only for read. */
}
```

Then you export your parts:

```
[Export(typeof (ICarPart))]
[ExportMetadata("NameCarPart","SteeringWheel")] /* is string!! */

public class SteeringWheel : ICarPart {

    public int SomeMethodFromInterface(){
        ... //your stuff
    }
}
[Export(typeof (ICarPart))]
[ExportMetadata("NameCarPart","Engine")] /* is string!! */

public class Engine : ICarPart {

    public int SomeMethodFromInterface(){
        //Each method have diferent behavior in each part.
        ... //your stuff
    }
}
[Export(typeof (ICarPart))]
[ExportMetadata("NameCarPart","Brakes")] /* is string!! */

public class Brakes : ICarPart {

    public int SomeMethodFromInterface(){
        //Each method have diferent behavior in each part.
        ... //your stuff
    }
}
```

Then you can import with ImportMany and Lazy:

```
    [ImportMany()]
    IEnumerable<Lazy<ICarPart, ICarPartMetadata>> carParts = null;
    public void Importing(){
    ...
    ...

    foreach (Lazy<ICarPart,ICarPartMetadata> item in carParts){
        switch (item.Metadata.ICarPartMetadata.ToString()){
            case "SteeringWheel":
                item.Value.SomeMethodFromInterface();
            break;
            case "Engine":
                item.Value.SomeMethodFromInterface();
            break;
            case "Brakes":
                item.Value.SomeMethodFromInterface();
            break;
            default:
            ...
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the advantage of this method over the one Adam proposes? Wouldn't this method require more overhead, and wouldn't this still at one point import ALL objects, only accessing methods of the ones you wish to use (i.e. those defined as cases)? If I end up with over 100 objects, this would hinder performance on plugins which only access 1 or 2 of those wouldn't it?

Comment: In case you need a few imports you can use the Adam method. In other hand, the Lazy class is useful when you have a lot of imports. -> "Lazy is actually used when your plugins are heavy and need large amount of memory" http://dailydotnettips.com/2011/09/02/getting-lazy-with-mef/

Comment: Additionally, you need a contract to ensure that your solution will be maintained over time since with a contract you can alter your export class without touch the main project. If you put the names without contracts will be very dependent on the parts and you will lose some MEF benefits.

Answer (score 10):

You can name the exports:

```
[Export("SteeringWheel", typeof(Part))]
```

When you want a specific one,

```
[Import("Engine", typeof(Part))]
```

You can still import many of type Part if you don't specify the name.

Comment: If my response solved your problem, make sure to mark it as the answer.

Comment: @AdamBarney, found your answer, doing the same in SL but it doesn't work, do you see anything obviously wrong? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39758390/exporting-by-type-and-contract-importmany-does-not-work-as-expected